# Need to Show around 20,000 pins on Google maps coming from Database result

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to show users as pins on google maps. I fetched records of users from database and they are now around 20,000. What i am doing right now is to do a ajax request to fetch all the users from database, once the document is loaded and map is created. But the issue is that when i respond the ajax call with json result of around 20,000 records, my browser get stuck. It sometimes takes 20 minutes to load the results and show them as pins on google maps. I am sure that this is the wrong way.

Can anyone guide me what could be the best way to load the database result as pins on google maps. Please keep in mind for each request the result set may be different(based on loggedin user's city - the idea is to show nearby users).

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `20,000` on a map at the same time would confuse your clients break it down to Categories .... only show about 100 at a time

Comment: Are 20000 nearby users really of interest? Can't you for example summarize them to places (ie 20 users are at Joe's bar, 250 at Dance Plaza etc...?) and show the summarized pins?

Comment: This is special case when user want to see nearby users from selected country. All other cases works fine because in those case number of users hugely get reduced. I am already using CLUSTERING. I just need to handle specific scenario at the moment to show nearby users of selected country(Its important requirement and i can't avoid it!)

Comment: With that many markers you need to use either custom tiles or *server side clustering*, V2 example: http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/

Answer (score 2):

With such a volume of data, it will be slow trying to draw 20,000 pins.

Look at something like clustering - http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html

Alternatively, if you're only showing nearby users, do you really have 20,000 nearby users? Narrow down the returned user list based on the user's current location.

Comment: That example uses the API V2, which is deprecated.

Comment: I am already using CLUSTERING

Comment: With that many markers you need to use either custom tiles or *server side clustering*, V2 example: http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/

Answer (score 1):

I would be keen to keep it below 100 pins really - for a device with low processing power 20,000 pins is FAR too much.

If you are sure that you need to render all of the pins, then you need to think carefully about how the information is fed to the user. Are you going to preload it all at the page load, so that the information can be reused or are you looking to reload the information if it changes.

Regardless, if you are outputting the results in XML for the Javascript to read, a smaller XML file gives a faster load time. If you are using XML you could reduce it from...

```
<records>
    <record id="1">
        <name>blah</name>
        <longatude>blah</longatude>
        <latitude>blah</latitude>
    </record>
        <record id="2">
        <name>blah</name>
        <longatude>blah</longatude>
        <latitude>blah</latitude>
    </record>
</records>
```

To:

```
<records>
    <record id="1" n="blah" lat="bah" lon="blah" />
    <record id="2" n="blah" lat="bah" lon="blah" />
    <record id="3" n="blah" lat="bah" lon="blah" />
</records>
```

If you are sure that all of the markers are required, I would use Google Maps Clustering mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) which will reduce the number rendered on the page at any one time.

Comment: I am already using Clustering. I need to load pins on page load.

Comment: Ah ok - then I would try to reduce down the JSON response like the XML above. 20 minutes seems excessive even for that many pins. If you are selecting by users near to a country then reducing the output to only those users will help. If the JSON contains information about the individual users remove it. When the user clicks on a pin - then do a AJAX call to the DB to fetch the information for example.

Comment: 20 minutes is the estimated time because ajax response with huge dataset consume lot of memory specially if u are working in FireFox :)

Comment: The things you need to do: 1 - Minimise the number of results you are parsing, 2 - Reduce the size of the result format, 3 - Use the clustering like you do, 4 - Test on a local machine and another server maybe for a comprarison. If none of that works, paste your code and we will have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I was just looking through this site [link](http://4-seasons.de/geonavigation), they are showing almost 2000 records/pins but rendering time is very fast.

Comment: On that example the pins aren't actually placed as such. I think they are just referenced. When I have done clusting before, if you zoom in - you will see the individual markers. On that example you do not, you only see the one marker that has the cluster count upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to avoid using the client. I have not tried this but Fusion Table Layers seem to be what you are after, it keeps the processing on googles servers and you can use sql like queries. there is a limit of 100,000 rows per table and 5 tables.

I am unsure of the setup of the table but it may be an interesting alternative to look at.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables